# Read a mat data file and to draw 2D vector out of it

Tags: arrays, matlab, 2d

Here is a bit of detail, I am from C++ old language background, while resolving Matlab question asked by my teacher.
I am given a mat file which contains real data, and I need to read it, assign the values to 2-D array, as a spike of waveform is a 2-D array. Plot it on X and Y axis.
Then I need to make a threshold by looking at spikes that most spikes are between, e.g, a range of this number so chop of the extra bit over, and take only spike (2-D array) which have under a certain threshold.
Spike means a simple signal which you see when a patient is sick and its heart beat is showing on screen.
My data file is 313 Mb in size. So can anyone guide me how to deal with this big file as well.

So any help code would be great.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html  Then formulate a real question showing what you tried and what's not working the way you want.

Comment: Sure thing high performance Mark :) I am reading the math works documentation. Here is my achievement so far.
I used following code
.
load ('rawspikes.mat') % time , waveform are two variable found in workspace , total were 806041 waveforms in workspace 
new_waveform = (1:80000) % this extracted first 80000 instances of waveforms and save to new_waveform

plot (1:80000,1) % this plotted the 1-80000 waveforms with respect to column 1 which I extracted from main variable

Now my task it fetch further specific waveforms going to a certain threshold
threshold=2.5e-5 %graph value

Comment: Now I need to make some kind of loop to pick the waveform which are specifically ending at certain threshold.
in 2D graph they are going from -2 to +2 ( - below than central axis and + being above the central axis.

I know for loop in C language.
but my Question is

Which value i can compare to threshold value to extract the waves forms which are going to certain threshold value in graph.

My thinking is , i need to save the waveform into a variable and compare it with the main threshold value which is threshold=2.5e-5

Comment: thanks for helping  :) any help with this  "High Mark Performance" or any different idea of logic to fetch wave forms of a certain threshold and draw it?

Answer (score 1):

Type the following in Matlab:

```
help load
```

Read it.  Then type:

```
help plot
```

Read it.  Make a start on your problem, then come back for help.

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried plot (time,waveform) and it drawn a spike wave form with lot of spikes on front of screen, 2 axis are there, x axis starting from -2 to 1.5(-2,-1.5,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5) , and Y axis starting from 0,1000, and goes to 10,000, meaning lot of data.
 How do I separate the one which have on X axis between -0.5 to 0.5 (or may be 0.3).
I think I need to access 2D array of time,waveform (workspace variables) and assign some kind of loop and condition on it.
Any idea mate.
Thanks a million.

Comment: It sounds like your axes are backwards.  "whos" will give you info on all the variables in your workspace.  "if" is for decision making.  "for" is for looping.  But you don't want to loop in Matlab if you can help it, because Matlab is vectorized -- looping slows it down by orders of magnitude.  See Andrew's answer.

Comment: Hi mate, I just mentioned above- I fetched the waveforms out of main variable and fetched first 1-80000 rows of it (the main variable of the mat file contain 806041X50 values
so i picked the 80000X1 (column of data) and plotted it, now I am looking for fetching certain threshold of waveforms out of it. at this moment they all are drawn to various points on graph. now if i want to fetch a certain values ones, i need to compare the waveform value to some threshold.
I studied Matlab has a graph values of 2.5e-5.
without using look as you said, it slows down how can i fetch many of certain waves?

Answer (score 1):

First load your .mat file into the current workspace:

```
load(filename)
```

filename would be something like 'data.mat'

After this you should have your 2D array in the workspace...let's assume it's named 'data'. If  the first row is the X axis and the second row is the Y axis, then use:

```
plot(data(1,:), data(2,:))
```

The ':' in MATLAB selects every column in the 2D array. You can then use the following to find all indexes of values over your threshold:

```
indexes = find(data(1,:) > threshold)
```

If you want to saturate these values at your threshold, then do:

```
data(1,indexes) = threshold
```

The size of your .mat file shouldn't change anything other than how long each function takes to complete.

Edit: You were vague and unclear in your problem statement, so hopefully I understood you correctly. Let me know if I didn't understand what you wanted.

Comment: Good suggestion guys. very help ful comments.
Andrew.
my File is called rawspikes.mat , so i loaded it into the matlab workspace with
load ('rawspikes.mat')
and in work space it loaded with 2 double type values

time 
waveform
Then I tried the above expression .
 plot (time(1,:),waveform(2,:))
it worked but instead of showing waveform it opened a window of figure one with so many small dots and one single line in middle of the figure one window.
What i am guessing is, there are two many values , so i might need to limit them. Secondly it is not showing a wave form like, sine wave.thanks heaps.

Comment: Andrew it worked a bit.
I tried plot (time,waveform) and it drawn a spike wave form with lot of spikes on front of screen, 2 axis are there, x axis starting from -2 to 1.5(-2,-1.5,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5) , and Y axis starting from 0,1000, and goes to 10,000, meaning lot of data. How do I separate the one which have on X axis between -0.5 to 0.5 (or may be 0.3). I think I need to access 2D array of time,waveform (workspace variables) and assign some kind of loop and condition on it. Any idea.

Comment: Note: "indexes" in Andrew's code is an array.  "find" is overloaded to work on vectors like "data(1,:)" (and any size array, actually).

Comment: I highly doubt there are too many values. Are you sure that your data is a row vector as opposed to a column vector? If you can add images to your original post or even a screenshot of your data vectors to help us understand what you're saying that would make it easier to help you. I'm having a hard time understanding some of your sentences.